# Lidando com JSON no PHP

Tags: php, json

Tenho uma função que consome uma API REST e que o *response* me retorna um arquivo JSON com muitos dados. Mas estou tento um erro ao converter esses dados para poder manipulá-lo de forma mas fácil.

Aqui vai um pequeno exemplo de um erro similar:

```
<?php
  $json = '{"dados"{"nome":"marcos"}}';
  $data = json_encode($json);
  $dados = json_decode($data,true);
  echo $dados["dados"]["nome"];
?>
```

Onde o erro é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
  $json = '{"dados"{"nome":"marcos"}}';
  $data = json_encode($json);
  $dados = json_decode($data);
  echo $dados->dados;
?>
```

Neste o erro é similar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma dica de como resolver? Os exemplos similares nos stack sempre mostram para utilizar o array assosiativo com o `json_decode($data, true)` mas fica gerando sempre o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, o JSON está errado, faltou colocar `:` entre a chave "dados" e o seu valor:

```
$json = '{"dados": {"nome":"marcos"}}';
                 ^ aqui
```

Segundo, se você tem uma string e quer transformar em um array, use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) diretamente. Nesse caso não faz sentido usar [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) para depois usar `json_decode`:

```
$json = '{"dados": {"nome":"marcos"}}';
$dados = json_decode($json, true);
echo $dados["dados"]["nome"]; // marcos
```

Ou, se quiser um objeto em vez de array associativo:

```
$json = '{"dados": {"nome":"marcos"}}';
$dados = json_decode($json);
echo $dados->dados->nome; // marcos
```

---

Apenas esclarecendo: se você tem uma string e quer transformar em um array/objeto, use `json_decode`. Se quer fazer o contrário (transformar o array/objeto em uma string), aí sim você usa `json_encode`.

Como o código começa com uma string, então usar `json_encode` não era necessário, bastando usar apenas `json_decode`.

Comment: O problema em estar utilizando o json_encode em um retorno ja em JSON. Removendo o json_encode ele funcionou.